# SQL server 2008 query slowness reported by NewRelic on one of table which is having proper indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, indexing, newrelic, query-performance

We are using ASP.NET MVC with nHibernate to fetch data from SQL server 2008. Recently we started using New Relic and noticed one of table (with around 6+ million rows in staging and 10+ million rows in production) is taking more time to return data with simple query (without any joins)

We have already verified indexes are present on required fields and database maintenance jobs are running properly.

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OfferTable](
[OfferID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Offer] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[IssueDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ExpiryDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [nvarchar](255) NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[OfferID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]. [OfferTable]') AND name = N'IX_OfferTable_Offer')
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_OfferTable_Offer] ON [dbo].[OfferTable] 
(
    [Offer] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

nHibernate is generating following query to fetch row from database (got from sql profiler)

```
exec sp_executesql N'select offertable0_.OfferId as OfferId22_, offertable0_.Offer as Offer_22, offertable0_.IssueDate as IssueDate22_, offertable0_.ExpiryDate as ExpiryDate22_,offertable0_.UserId as UserId22_ from OfferTable  offertable0_  where (offertable0_.Offer is null) and (@p0 is null) or offertable0_.Offer=@p0',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Someoffer'
```

Query execution plan showing Index Seek for Offer field then Key Lookup on OfferID (clustered index) followed by Nested Loops

Command with SET STATISTICS IO ON giving following output

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'OfferTable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

According to NewRelic above query is very volatile, takes any where between 600 ms to 29,300 ms which is unacceptable. While executing same query directly from SQL Management Studio takes no time at all.

Even NewRelic reported slowness for this query with 26,800 ms.

```
SELECT offertable_.OfferId AS col_0_0_ FROM OfferTable offertable_ WHERE offertable_.OfferId=@p0
```

We were able to get DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS for staging environment as we don't have direct access to databases.

```
Name                              Updated              Rows      Rows Sampled  Steps  Density  Average key length String Index Filter Expression    Unfiltered Rows
--------------------------------- -------------------- --------- ------------- ------ -------- ------------------ ------------ -------------------- --------------------
PK__OfferTab__8EBCF0B1762C88DA    Feb 17 2014 11:47PM  6471738   87058         196    1        4                  NO           NULL                 6471738


All density   Average Length Columns
------------- -------------- ---------------
2.51234E-07   4              OfferId

RANGE_HI_KEY RANGE_ROWS    EQ_ROWS       DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
------------ ------------- ------------- -------------------- --------------
2077         0             1             0                    1
254978       33824.68      1             33823                1.000041
255503       38071.39      1             524                  72.65533
425848       18998.45      1             18998                1
572688       38071.39      1             38061                1.000283
573083       28534.92      1             394                  72.42365
808660       38071.39      1             38061                1.000283
865309       38071.39      1             38061                1.000283
1466077      38071.39      1             38061                1.000283
1466464      28534.92      1             386                  73.92466
1491230      38071.39      1             24765                1.537306
1703369      18998.45      1             18998                1

  ......


72632182     38071.39      1             38061                1.000283
72632801     38071.39      1             618                  61.6042
72633595     38071.39      1             793                  48.00932
72635990     38071.39      1             2394                 15.90284
72647229     38071.39      1             11238                3.387738
72647764     33973.69      1             534                  63.62114
72647766     0.9999998     1             1                    1


Name                 Updated              Rows     Rows Sampled  Steps  Density       Average key length String Index Filter Expression  Unfiltered Rows
-------------------- -------------------- -------- ------------- ------ ------------- ------------------ ------------ ------------------ --------------------
IX_OfferTable_Offer  Feb 17 2014 12:12AM  6694454  94967         195    1             60                 YES          NULL               6694454

All density   Average Length Columns
------------- -------------- ----------------
1.493774E-07  56             Offer
1.493774E-07  60             Offer, OfferId

RANGE_HI_KEY                                       RANGE_ROWS    EQ_ROWS       DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
-------------------------------------------------- ------------- ------------- -------------------- --------------
//+7ubDjuOYu54oCOmn9yqoSaGY=                       0             1             0                    1
/EiSLpejJg0iL3CIWpUwpHrKuN0=                       32068.48      1             32068                1
/Vdj7sd2XQYqH1fULVIjcvEKpNk=                       54177.36      1             54138                1.000732
+ATAAsm2GiZT8p6nq5PcoKP6WwM=                       36094.7       1             36091                1.000089
+ijb5mACGIixMdHwZ7bbN8d3wPE=                       27053.36      1             27053                1
+tIz35UIZ+5lMJAVJIloZ/UNBks=                       36094.7       1             36091                1.000089
06PLbtzHQ5d0011ruV3JKngyHX4=                       36094.7       1             36091                1.000089
0j9ZQAfUIfmuGmWnhvY2dDzyjgo=                       36094.7       1             36091                1.000089
0rDVT9rzqhHioz7DEFWs1surUr0=                       27053.36      1             27053                1
11ybw3Kws7ral/jxwmGvhcPqLSA=                       36094.7       1             36091                1.000089
1KEbJtyPiSI4+uyqipqU8TzFvLM=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
1VnZxvlS1zb7TvQYHaF1NLz+X/Y=                       36094.7       1             36091                1.000089
26qVdhVKpWdPnkc0F1cpPhCxZE8=                       27053.36      1             27053                1
2joJSKCwIdoOHuiXu3nh+TeugGU=                       36094.7       1             36091                1.000089

 .....

YCRN93l3z9kZq9O8XmhTkfAc4t0=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
YJpsDBYjGsM8E00Qso5jA2pEDvQ=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
YqYLAWj3RAy1Eds1U5AJ3v6LyDI=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
yxwmZJ4u++qKMFUZ3BLuRUVEECo=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
Z6qEakF5+YM1ufMQud2tnSWbPXs=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
ZF9irQvOCQRkt2s4Af7AftxHF2w=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
ZLWmCLRC4tfKQ721jJRXB2WrE2s=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
zsl5/65fRzNsVrHwRmB3Ta29e94=                       45136.03      1             45115                1.000474
ZZZHu1NznjtILSTYu/6jp5CK0mY=                       48455.89      1             48428                1.00058
```

We also used Database Engine Tuning Advisor which recommended new index with include  (covering index)

Please can anyone help me to understand why NewRelic is reporting query slowness? Is something related with nHibernate? Should use covering index and why?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Should the criteria be `(@p0 is null or offertable0_.Offer=@p0')` instead of `(@p0 is null) or offertable0_.Offer=@p0'`? Fixing that should significantly improve performance when the parameter is null. A common cause for slow queries is that the column is varchar but NHibernate supplies an nvarchar parameter, however that appears to not be the case here.

If you frequently select using criteria on Offer then an index would likely be a big help. But since the query by primary key `SELECT offertable_.OfferId AS col_0_0_ FROM OfferTable offertable_ WHERE offertable_.OfferId=@p0` exhibits the same problem then I suspect you have a different root cause.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. Yes it's look like some other issue, we have involved DBAs to check what is going on.